# How should i get another redirected page url in python?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

Like we open a URL to a normal browser so it will redirect to another website url. Example a shorted link. After you open this it will redirect you to the main url.

So how to do this in python I mean I need to open a URL on python and this will redirect to other website page then I will copy the other website page link.

That's all I want to know thank you.

I tried it with python `requests` and `urllib` module.

Like this

```
import requests

a = requests.get("url", allow_redirects = True)
```

And

```
import urllib.request

a = urllib.request.urlopen("url")
```

But it's not working at all. I mean didn't get the redirected page.

Comment: there are 3 types of redirections. (1) server sends response with status 3xx and new address, (2) server sends HTML with tag `<meta refresh="time;url">` (3) JavaScript can set `document.location = url` (or similar). `Requests` automatically redirect for first type. For second type It is easy to check if HTML has meta tag and run next request with new url. But third type makes problem because requests can't run JavaScript and there are many different method to assign new location.

Answer (score 2):

I know 4 types of redirections.

1. server sends response with status 3xx and new address

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
   Location: https://new_domain.com/some/folder
   ```

   Wikipedia: [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), [HTTP 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303)
2. server sends header `Refresh` with time in seconds and new address

   ```
   Refresh: 0; url=https://new_domain.com/some/folder
   ```
3. server sends HTML with meta tag which emulates header `Refresh`

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://new_domain.com/some/folder">
   ```

   Wikipedia: [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)
4. JavaScript sets new location

   ```
   location = url
   location.href = url
   location.replace(url)
   location.assing(url)
   ```

   The same for `document.location`, `window.location`

   There should be also combination with `open()`,`document.open()`, `window.open()`

---

`requests` automatically redirects for first and (probably) second type. With `urllib` probably you would have to check status, get url, and run next request - but this is easy. You can even run it in loop because some pages may have many redirections. You can test it on [httpbin.org](https://httpbin.org/#/Redirects) (even for multi-redirections)

For third type it is easy to check if HTML has meta tag and run next request with new url. And again you can run in loop because some pages may have many redirections.

But forth type makes problem because `requests` can't run JavaScript and there are many different methods to assign new location. They can also hide it in code - `"obfuscation"`.

---

In `requests` you can check `response.history` to see executed redirections